On the trajectory followed by a point P on a planar convex region C when P is mapped repeatedly to the farthest point to it on C
Consider a planar convex region $C$. Let us define a mapping of a point $P$ on $C$ to that point on C that is farthest from $P$. Obviously, if from an initial position of $P$, we do this mapping repeatedly, $P$ traces out a trajectory.
For example, if $C$ is a rectangle, from any point $P$ on it, the mapping takes $P$ to a corner of $C$ and further applications of the mapping merely causes $P$ to keep switching between two ends of a diagonal.
Question: Given any positive integer $n$, can one find some $C$ and some initial $P$ on it such that the trajectory of $P$ when the mapping is repeated $n$ times has all the $n$ points different? If for a $P$, there are many different farthest points to it, we are free to choose any one from them as the next point in the trajectory and proceed.
Observations: We checked numerically the case when $C$ is an ellipse and $P$ is initially a random point on the boundary. If the eccentricity of $C$ is low, we find that the number of times the mapping can be done before the position of $P$ coincides with its position in an earlier iteration is quite high (we could go up to 40) but seems always finite. It also seems that for any ellipse, the initial position of $P$ that maximizes the number of iterations before position of $P$ repeats is an end of the minor axis of $C$. If $C$ has high eccentricity, $P$ repeats after very few iterations. It is not clear with the precision that we could manage whether $P$ really hits a repetition with finitely many iterations or only tends rapidly to a repetition but actually needs infinitely many iterations to get there.
Further questions: Going to 3D, one can have multiple variants of this question by (1) considering $C$ as a solid 3D convex region or (2) the surface of such a region with the farthest point to any $P$ being defined either in terms of geodesics or in terms of paths which lie entirely on a plane (these two definitions also feature in 'Uniformity' of surfaces of 3D convex solids). One can also ask about metrics other than Euclidean.

My colleague Costin Vilcu pointed to Schwartz, Richard Evan. "The Farthest Point Map on the Regular Octahedron." Experimental Mathematics 31, no. 4 (2022): 1086-1097, and its ten references on related investigations of the farthest point map.

If we are free to break ties in any way we want, doesn't a regular (2N+1)-gon work? each vertex has two farthest points that are also vertices, and the trajectory that always chooses the one on the right will not repeat itself until it visits all vertices.

Thanks for the pointer to 'farthest point maps'. And yes, the regular 2N+1-gon does seem to work all right as a simple answer to the basic question above! thanks. Guess it could be more interesting to see if we can achieve exactly N iterations before first repetition with a C that has no ties.

Another paper just posted: "The farthest point map on the 4-cube." arXiv abs.
